# OWIN Cookie middleware with web.config authorization elements

Tags: asp.net, cookies, owin, openid-connect, katana

I have been struggling for several days with a strange issue with OWIN cookie middleware (3.0.1).

I have recreated the issue with a minimal code example. First create an empty ASP.NET web application project (VS.NET 2015). And the OWIN nuget packages etc... And a basic Startup class here:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            // context.Response.StatusCode = 200 here
            Debug.WriteLine("1. ==> Request - Before Cookie Auth");
            await next();
            // context.Response.StatusCode = 401 here
            Debug.WriteLine("4. <== Response - After Cookie Auth");
        });

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        // by adding this element to web.config, the next middle is no longer used, the request ends with 401.2
        // <authorization>
        //    <deny users="?" />
        // </authorization>

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            // I thought this middleware would be hit so it could deal with 401 - issue challenge
            // e.g. app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication etc...
            Debug.WriteLine("2. ==> After Cookie Auth, Never Hit!! if web.config has <authorization>< deny users = \"?\" /> ");
            await next();
            Debug.WriteLine("3. <== Never hit");
        });
    }
}
```

The code works as expected until I add the follow element to the web.config

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

My second OWIN middleware now no longer gets called. In this example, its simple logging statements but in a larger project its app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication.

My understanding was that the 401 status would be dealt with by other authentication middleware and in turn create a challenge response.

But nothing after the cookie middleware is being called. The response simply returns with a 401.2

This happens with both Local IIS and IIS Express.

Answer (score 3):

Add following code after app.UseCookieAuthentication:

```
app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
```

This will instruct Owin to run in the integrated pipeline.

Comment: This is redundant. `app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate)` is already called from within app.UseCookieAuthentication().

Answer (score 1):

`app.UseCookieAuthentication()` calls `app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate)` which makes all the OMCs (Owin middleware Components) already registered (including the Cookie one) run in `AuthenticateRequest` integrated pipeline stage.

The OMCs that are registered after this UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate) call will be scheduled in a later stage, usually the last one available: `PreHandlerExecute`.

When you add `<deny users="?" />`, IIS will return 401 from that stage in the pipeline, therefore the rest of the middlewares scheduled to run at a later stage will not be invoked.

You just need to move the app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate) [mentioned by Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37615187/121257) after the OMCs you want to also be invoked.

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline) explains pretty well how OWIN Middleware executes in the IIS integrated pipeline.